# it is not working can somebody give any suggestions?

Tags: reactjs

```
const ExpenseDate = (props) => {
  const month = props.date.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "long" });
  const day = props.date.toLocaleString("en-US", { day: "2-digit" });
  const year = props.date.getFullYear();
```

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLocaleString' of undefined
ExpenseDate**

```
    C:/Users/MSI/OneDrive/Desktop/Projects/01-starting-setup/src/components/Expenses/ExpenseDate.js:6
      3 | import "./ExpenseDate.css";
      4 | 
      5 | const ExpenseDate = (props) => {
    > 6 |   const month = props.date.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "long" });
      7 |   const day = props.date.toLocaleString("en-US", { day: "2-digit" });
      8 |   const year = props.date.getFullYear();
      9 |
```

Comment: probably props.date is undefined initially

Answer (score 1):

Add basic validation, cause your `date` is somehow `undefined` (probably shortly after mount), then it should work:

```js
const ExpenseDate = (props) => {
const month = props.date?.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "long" });
const day = props.date?.toLocaleString("en-US", { day: "2-digit" });
const year = props.date?.getFullYear();
```

Comment: Do the `?` characters add validation to `props.date`?

Comment: thank you it worked

Comment: @admcfajn no it's `?.` optional chaining. it returns nullish(null or undefined)  instead of causing error when iteration fails

Comment: It's `?.` will convert it to `null` if current (in this case `date`) property is `null` or `undefined` instead of calling rest of methods in chain.